# Implementing LoG blob detector in python and openCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to implement an LoG blob detector according to the algortihm in wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_detection#The_Laplacian_of_Gaussian

I'm using Python and openCV and I'm using a code I got for making the filters, my code creates n level of filters, use the filters on the image and saves all the levels in an h*w*n array.
Afterwards I look for local maxima and if I find one I mark it as the center of a blob and draw a circle around it.
I managed to get it to work but I'm getting weird results and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
myImage = cv2.imread('fishes.jpg')
n = 15
height, width = myImage.shape[:2]
empty = np.empty((height+2,width+2)).astype(np.uint8)
imgArray = np.empty((n+2,height+2,width+2)).astype(np.uint8)
radArray = []
imgArray[0] = empty
imgArray[n+1] = empty
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(myImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayAllChannels = cv2.cvtColor(gray_image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
sigma = 2
k = 2**(0.25)
std2 = float(sigma**2)
for i in range(n):
    filt_size =  2*np.ceil(3*sigma)+1
    radArray.append(filt_size / 2)
    H = log_filt( filt_size, sigma)
    H *= sigma**2
    dst = cv2.filter2D(gray_image,-1,H)
    dst = cv2.copyMakeBorder(dst,1,1,1,1,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=BLACK)
    imgArray[i+1] = dst      
    sigma = sigma * k
    std2 = float(sigma**2)

i = 0
for imgIndex in range(1,n+1):
    for hIndex in range(1, height+1):
        for wIndex in range(1, width+1):
            tSlice = imgArray[imgIndex - 1:imgIndex + 2,hIndex - 1:hIndex + 2,wIndex - 1:wIndex + 2]
            tNum = imgArray[imgIndex,hIndex,wIndex]
            if (tNum > imgArray[imgIndex - 1,hIndex - 1,wIndex - 1] and
                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex - 1,hIndex - 1,wIndex] and
                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex - 1,hIndex - 1,wIndex + 1] and
                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex - 1,hIndex,wIndex - 1] and
                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex - 1,hIndex,wIndex] and
                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex - 1,hIndex,wIndex + 1] and
                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex - 1,hIndex + 1,wIndex - 1] and
                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex - 1,hIndex + 1,wIndex] and
                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex - 1,hIndex + 1,wIndex + 1] and

                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex,hIndex - 1,wIndex - 1] and
                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex,hIndex - 1,wIndex] and
                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex,hIndex - 1,wIndex + 1] and
                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex,hIndex,wIndex - 1] and
                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex,hIndex ,wIndex + 1] and
                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex,hIndex + 1,wIndex - 1] and
                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex,hIndex + 1,wIndex] and
                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex,hIndex + 1,wIndex + 1] and

                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex + 1,hIndex - 1,wIndex - 1] and
                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex + 1,hIndex - 1,wIndex] and
                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex + 1,hIndex - 1,wIndex + 1] and
                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex + 1,hIndex,wIndex - 1] and
                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex + 1,hIndex,wIndex] and
                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex + 1,hIndex,wIndex + 1] and
                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex + 1,hIndex + 1,wIndex - 1] and
                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex + 1,hIndex + 1,wIndex] and
                tNum > imgArray[imgIndex + 1,hIndex + 1,wIndex + 1]):

                cv2.circle(grayAllChannels,(hIndex - 1, wIndex - 1),np.int16(radArray[imgIndex - 1]),(0,30,230),2)
```

I'm getting this result:

[image: butterfly]

Where the right result should be something like this:

[image: correct butterfly]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: The right result should be like this: https://youtu.be/L77m5xuDSKw?t=23m10s -- As I understand LoG blob detector is only a part of SIFT algorithm. It should give you the whole variety of blobs for different scales without orientation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that you confuse column/row respectively y/x somewhere (There are no blobs on the right half of the image)? 
If I should guess, I would say during the drawing the circles. I think you have to pass points in the format `(x, y)`, which means you have to exchange your values.

Comment: Yeah, that was one problem that I already solved, but the algorithm results still looks weird, I will post a new picture when I get home

Comment: Perfect. One more thought: A typical LoG filter results in negative values for white blobs. It looks like that you search only for maxima. Try computing the absolute value first (Or invert it, if you just want the white blobs).

Comment: thanks, dark blobs will do for now, I can always take the negative and run the algorithm again